# Animation not working when adding class to parent

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I'm making a modal window but the animation doesn't work.
It is necessary to make the white part come out from above.

I do not want to resort to using JS, since the same scheme is used by bootstrap and everything works for it.

Here is an example

```js
$("#test").on("click", function() { 
  $(".dropdown-modal").addClass("dropdown-modal--active")
})
```

```css
.dropdown-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1060;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown-modal--active {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-modal__contaner {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transform: translate(0, -90%);
}
.dropdown-modal--active .dropdown-modal__contaner {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Opne</button>
<div class="dropdown-modal">
   <div class="dropdown-modal__contaner">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work at the moment is because you can not animate it by only changing the `display` property from `none` to `block`.
I have modified the CSS to cause the menu to "slide in from the top":

```css
.dropdown-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1060;
  top: -100%; /* push it above the visible portion of the page by its height */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-out; /* set the top property to be animated */
}
.dropdown-modal--active {
  top: 0; /* return it back to the default position so it can be seen */
}

.dropdown-bg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
} 

.dropdown-bg--active { 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#test").on("click", function() { 
    $(".dropdown-modal").addClass("dropdown-modal--active")
    $(".dropdown-bg").addClass("dropdown-bg--active")
  })
  $(".dropdown-modal").on("click", function() { 
    $(".dropdown-modal").removeClass("dropdown-modal--active")
    $(".dropdown-bg").removeClass("dropdown-bg--active")
  })
  // Added an event listener to allow you to toggle the menu by clicking
  // on the menu to close it, this can be moved to be on a button click.
})
```

```html
<button id="test">Open</button>
<div class='dropdown-bg'></div>
<div class="dropdown-modal">
   <div class="dropdown-modal__contaner">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: changed code to add a background div that will appear with a grey background where the menu moves in from the top, based on comments.

Comment: You made a scheme in which the parent block leaves, that is, a black background, but I need a white block to leave on a black background.

Comment: I adapted it a bit for my task but it still doesn't work

Comment: Updated the post, hopefully this is what you are trying to get

Comment: I'm sorry! But I just did the same and it worked, but you gave the correct answer.